# CSS generator for div based tables

Tags: html, css

I found some websites that generates CSS for `<table>` like http://tablestyler.com/ http://www.csstablegenerator.com/ etc, but i have no luck for getting css generator for `DIV` based tables or grids.

Can anybody suggest some websites that generates CSS and tables/grids usings `DIV` tags?

Thanks for sharing your time.

Comment: if your dealing with tabular data then you should always use `<table>` markup, as this is what the `<table>` tag is for. You should never use `<table>` for layout purposes.

Comment: Why do you want to generate div based table if you have `<table>`. Divs are good for layouts and other stuff that already don't have their own tags.

Comment: This sort of poll question is not appropriate for [SO].

Comment: I know <table> is used for showing tabular data, but the rendering takes long time if i am presenting hundreds of records.

Comment: @IrfanRaza: and what makes you believe that with _divs_ it will be that much faster?

Comment: While I don't agree that <table> is faster than <div> at time I have wished that I could find such a thing too :-)  But then I just write my own divTable.  It is quite useful for not only laying out data but also building structure...

Answer (score 2):

**[CSS DIV Table Generator](http://www.cssbuttoncode.com/table.php)**

> This is a powerful javascript div table layout generator and creator that is compatible with firefox, internet explorer 7, ie8 to versions to ie 9, opera,netscape etc.

Comment: This solves my problem up to some extent, but what i was searching for css effects (like gradients) as presented by http://www.csstablegenerator.com/, thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

[Layzilla](http://www.layzilla.com/) is the only web-based one that comes to mind, but you'll probably find it easier just writing markup or using something more powerful like Dreamweaver.